# IndexError: list index out of range error through for loop

Tags: python

I'm running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd

datacsv = pd.read_csv("games.csv", sep=",")
data = datacsv["moves"]
winners = datacsv["winner"]
victory_stat = datacsv["victory_status"]
winnercolor = []
gmoves = []  # holds good moves
movesfinal = []  # holds best moves

i = 0
for i in range(0, 20057):
    winnercolor.append(winners[i])

for i in range(0, len(winnercolor)):
    if winnercolor[i] == 'black':
        temp_move = data[i]
        gmoves.append(temp_move)
        if victory_stat[i] == 'mate':
            temp_fmove = data[i]
            movesfinal.append(temp_fmove)


gmoves.clear()
for y in (0, len(gmoves)-1):
    oldlist = str(gmoves[y])
    newlist = oldlist.split(sep=" ")
    gmoves.append(newlist)

print(gmoves)
```

however I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/AITest.py", line 28, in <module>
    oldlist = str(gmoves[y])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, though I think it has something to do with the for loop iterating too far, although I'm not sure why this is happening. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `gmoves.clear()` empties the list so the tuple `(0, len(gmoves)-1)` will evaluate to `(0, -1)` but both `0` and `-1` can't be the index to an empty list (in fact nothing can).
It's weird that that delete all the elements inside `gmoves` just before using it.